# Cambiar el background-color si está pulsado

Tags: angular, typescript

Quiero que al hacer el click el background-color de mi div se cambie para saber que he está pulsado, el problema que me encuentro es que al ser un *ngFor si cambio el color del div al pulsar se me cambia en todos

```
<div class="col-md-6 card">
            <div class="card-header-submenu">
                <span><i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i> Visitas</span> 
            </div>
            <div class="card-body-citas">
                <div *ngFor='let fhistoria of historial' class="visitas mt-1" (click)="modificate(false);modificarci(true);auxHistorial(fhistoria.datos,fhistoria.fecha,fhistoria.hora)">
                    <span>{{fhistoria.fecha}} - {{fhistoria.hora}}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

Así es como se ve

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Puedes compartir el código de la función que realiza el cambio de color de fondo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te recomiendo usar sólo una función en el evento `click, pasando de esto:

```
<div class="col-md-6 card">
  <div class="card-header-submenu">
    <span><i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i> Visitas</span> 
  </div>
  <div class="card-body-citas">
    <div *ngFor='let fhistoria of historial' class="visitas mt-1" 
          (click)="modificate(false); modificarci(true);auxHistorial(fhistoria.datos,fhistoria.fecha,fhistoria.hora)">
      <span>{{fhistoria.fecha}} - {{fhistoria.hora}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

a esto:

```
<div class="col-md-6 card">
  <div class="card-header-submenu">
    <span><i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i> Visitas</span> 
  </div>
  <div class="card-body-citas">
    <div *ngFor='let fhistoria of historial' class="visitas mt-1"
        (click)="onFHistoriaClicked(fhistoria)">
      <span>{{fhistoria.fecha}} - {{fhistoria.hora}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

con un método en el componente así:

```
onFHistoriaClicked(fhistoria) {
  modificate(false);
  modificarci(true);
  auxHistorial(fhistoria.datos, fhistoria.fecha, fhistoria.hora);
}
```

---

Una vez hecho esto, puedes añadir un *flag* para indicar que se ha pulsado:

```
onFHistoriaClicked(fhistoria) {
  modificate(false);
  modificarci(true);
  auxHistorial(fhistoria.datos, fhistoria.fecha, fhistoria.hora);

  fhistoria.clicked = !fhistoria.clicked; //cada click cambia entre false y true
}
```

Y añadir la clase CSS que cambia el color dependiendo de este flag:

```
<div class="col-md-6 card">
  <div class="card-header-submenu">
    <span><i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i> Visitas</span> 
  </div>
  <div class="card-body-citas">
    <div *ngFor='let fhistoria of historial' class="visitas mt-1"
        (click)="onFHistoriaClicked(fhistoria)" [ngClass] = "{'pulsado': fhistoria.clicked}">
      <span>{{fhistoria.fecha}} - {{fhistoria.hora}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Este hilo [ya existe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35405618/ngfor-with-index-as-value-in-attribute), aunque está en inglés así que te traduzco.
Deberías utilizar un índice para cada elemento y así ejecutar el evento sobre ese indice. Sería algo así:

```
<div *ngFor='let fhistoria of historial; let i = index" [attr.data-index]="i"' class="visitas mt-1" (click)="modificate(false);modificarci(true);auxHistorial(fhistoria.datos,fhistoria.fecha,fhistoria.hora)">
    <span>{{fhistoria.fecha}} - {{fhistoria.hora}}</span>
</div>
```